# no access to encrypted partition after failed distro upgrade

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, upgrade, encryption, encrypted-partition

I had an Ubuntu 10.10 encrypted (dm-crypt) installation on my PC. Today i did the distro upgrade to 11.04, but the upgrade failed. There are no working system on my PC anymore.

How can i now access data on my encrypted /home partition? I remember my password exactly, but i don't have that hash, wich was generated on setup of that 10.10 encrypted installation.

In livecd session, it asks for password, but it wount work - no access.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/38336/how-do-i-recover-my-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory

Answer (score 0):

See this one
[How do I recover my data from an encrypted home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38336/how-do-i-recover-my-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory)

Comment: no t working, because i don't have encrypted home partition, the entire system is encrypted: I have in my Places menu:
255MB Filesystem
164GB Encrypted
43GB Encrypted
37GB Encrypted