# Unable to login to desktop

Tags: login, xubuntu, lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I recover my data from an encrypted home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38336/how-do-i-recover-my-data-from-an-encrypted-home-directory)

Something seems to be preventing me from logging into Xubuntu. I've attempted to retrieve my files by booting into a Live environment but the folder was encrypted. How should I approach this?

Comment: exactly what did you do for your situation?

Comment: What did you do that might have caused this (changed settings? installed software? etc.), or is this just suddenly happening?

Comment: What have you done? Have you perhaps installed anny drivers? Looks like a crashing X server. If there are any installed, try using a different desktop environment.

Comment: Did you try to [switch to console mode](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg24t8.htm) and log in? If it's an X issue, using the console may allow you to accessing your files and copy them to usb / floppy / network drive. But you will have to use the standard linux tools like `ls`, `cp`, `cd` and so on to work with your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl+alt+F1, it will bring you to text console. Enter your username and pass, and see what's going on. You will know if it's X Server fault or login credentials are incorrect.

If you log in, copy your data to USB stick.