# Copy Home folder from previous install

Tags: permissions, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

I recently attempted to update from 14.04 to 16.04, unfortunately my power went out and the computer shutdown breaking my installation, so I reinstalled without formatting.

I figured this would be no problem since I was able to keep the original `/home/user` file and I could just copy my files onto an external once a working install was running.

Sadly the new install seems to be a bit wonky as well so I am planning to just format and reinstall as soon as I am able to copy my files from the old home folder.

I've gotten as far as running:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /home/user
```

which successfully mounted the old home folder in `/tmp` after inputting the encryption key, or so it seems.

The problem is that when I try to launch `nautilus` from the terminal and view the files in the `/temp/ecryptfs/xxxx` to copy them, it's just the file `access-your-private-data.desktop` and the README file telling me to run `ecryptfs-mount-private`. But this always returns:

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

If I open the `.desktop` file it opens a terminal asking for login password. I enter the password then something opens and closes very rapidly then nothing.

I tried following someone's directions to setup a new user account and make it the new owner of the old `/home/user`, with the same result.

I have an external hd, a flash drive formated as a liveOS, and even a second comp at the ready.

How can I access my files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recovering eCryptfs partition with ecryptfs-recover-private not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93975/recovering-ecryptfs-partition-with-ecryptfs-recover-private-not-working)

Comment: Solution here: http://askubuntu.com/a/104317/271

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it by following the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93975/recovering-ecryptfs-partition-with-ecryptfs-recover-private-not-working). First, unmount whatever `gvfs` is. It's apparently causing problems. So for me this looked like:

```
umount /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

Now, an important oversight. You need to direct the ecryptfs recovery command not to the `/home/user`, but to the `.Private` directory! For whatever reason it says success, but is lying if you point it to the `/home/user`.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private
```

Now you should have **actual** success and be able to launch `nautilus` and access the files

Comment: here are the relevant answers I found that "cracked the case" for me, so to speak:
[link]https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77453/why-cannot-find-read-run-user-1000-gvfs-even-though-it-is-running-as-root
[link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/93975/recovering-ecryptfs-partition-with-ecryptfs-recover-private-not-working

Comment: Well done for figuring this out, and thanks for sharing. For future note — you probably know what's coming — please do a full backup before any major update.