# ecrytfs - purpose of Private.sig and Private.mnt?

Tags: files, configuration, ecryptfs

I just switched to `ecryptfs` and like it in conjunction with incremental backups.
But, what I have not understood is what are `Private.sig` and `Private.mnt` files used fore. Why should they be kept especially save for backup as well?

Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 8):

`Private.mnt` is a configuration file read by [`mount.ecryptfs_private`](http://manpg.es/mount.ecryptfs_private) at login that defines where your encrypted directory should be mounted.  If you've encrypted your home directory, this will be `$HOME`.  But some people choose to encrypt some other directory, perhaps a subset of `$HOME`, like `$HOME/Private`.

`Private.sig` contains "signatures" or "hashes" of your encryption keys.  These are used as "handles" to identify the keys in use.  It provides a safe, secure mechanism for eCryptfs to determine *if* you're using the correct key or not.

**Both of these are absolutely required and [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org) will NOT function properly with out them!!!**

*Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors and maintainers of [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org).*

Comment: The man page for `mount.ecryptfs_private` states it uses ~/.ecryptfs/Private.sig but not Private.mnt -- it says it always uses `$HOME/Private as the DESTINATION`. Is the man page correct?

Comment: Looking at the source only `ecryptfs-setup-private` and `ecryptfs-verify` use it?