# How to rename a user with an eCryptfs encrypted home directory?

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs, user-management

I just want to change the username of a user with an encrypted home directory. Is there a simple way instead of the suggested restoring and so forth?

- [How can i move an encrypted home directory to another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17332/40581)
- [How do I move my encrypted /home to a new computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124174/40581)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's best to **unmount** your home directory and execute the commands from another administrator account on the computer. You could use `ecryptfs-umount-private` or just reboot to unmount the directory.
2. **Change** the login name and directory name from `old_user` to `new_user`:

   ```
   sudo usermod -l new_user -m -d /home/new_user old_user
   ```
3. Here comes the important part for the proper **configuration**:

   - There exists a file named `/home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt` it usually contains the following: `/home/$USER`
   - The following symlinks exist in your home directory when eCryptfs is not mounted:

     ```
     .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs
     .Private ->  /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.Private
     ```
   - Make sure that `$USER` in all these instances reflects the changes you intended to make, e.g. `new_user`. You can use `nano` to edit text files and `ln -s` to create new symlinks.

You should be able to login again. I just tried it on my own. If you cannot log in through the GUI try from the terminal and check again that everything is in place.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu does this work on? (Just in case it doesn't work on a future/past version)

Comment: @Xen2050 Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/298251/40581) answer I'd say it should work on all non-EOL releases. In this example though I actually used Fedora 29. I made similar modifications to Ubuntu hosts years ago like providing an unencrypted `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for remote login, so I'd say once you understood where your data and configuration is and how the individual parts come together it's pretty basic and solid.

Comment: This worked for me, except renaming the `/home/.ecryptfs/$USER` directory. If I rename it, I can no longer access the directory, regardless if I change the reference in the files in my home directory. No biggie though, I don't mind if that directory has a different name, it's hidden inside `.ecryptfs` directory anyway.